# Do I need to reindex an index if I change the definition of an function in the indexes expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have created a btree on an expression involving a function in postgresql.

```
create table t (x int);

create function f(t) returns int
language sql immutable
as $function$
    select x + 1;
$function$

create index i on t (f(x));
```

Say I change the definition of `f` to;

```
create or replace function f(t) returns int
language sql immutable
as $function$
    select x + 2; -- Notice the difference!
$function$
```

Do I have to manually `reindex i` or will postgresql do that for me when I update the definition? If I don't `reindex` will my index become invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out postgresql will let you change the function definition without complaining and will only update the key of the btree when those rows are updated. The key will be inconsistent but postgresql still thinks the index is valid.

Also, in case anyone else tries anything like this. The (only?) consistent way to make this change is to;

1. transaction 1: create a new function
2. transaction 1: create a new index with that function
3. transaction 2: drop the old index
4. transaction 2: drop the old function

using `reindex` required an access exclusive lock on `t` so just building a new index means **you can keep your reads online**!